# Why is db.auth() only working after selecting a particular database?

Tags: mongodb

Right after I launch `mongo`, running

```
db.auth("admin", "myGreatPassword")
```

returns `0`. But doing this:

```
use admin
db.auth("admin", "myGreatPassword")
```

returns `1`.

I find this strange because the `admin` user has root privileges and can access all databases and do anything.

What could be the reason for the above behavior? Why do I need to first select a particular database, in this case `admin`, to log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mongodb you authenticate against a particular database: that database contains the collections that define the users and their roles. That user may then be authorised to do things on multiple databases, but the act of logging in happens against a specific database.

When using the command line tools this is the --authenticationDatabase option, in the mongo shell the authentication commands run against the current database.

Comment: Hey. I created the user like this: `db.createUser({user: "admin", pwd: "myGreatPassword", roles: [{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})`. Is it that last `db` key that determined which database the logging in "happens against"? Or was it the currently active database, prior to running createUser(), that determined it?

Comment: Are you also able to provide some thought about why "the act of logging in happens against a specific database"? Why is this a useful feature, if subsequent commands (after login) have technically nothing to do with this "login database"?

Comment: Currently active database when creating users is what matters. I don't know the rationale for this.